# Is it illegal to transfer money to people in foreign countries?

Tags: money-transfer, scams, transfer

A friend keeps sending money to foreign countries to guys she calls friends and recently began asking me to do it for her through Western Union.

Can I get in trouble for this?

Comment: Yes.  If they are sending her money, and she sends it back, then she's accessory to money laundering.

Comment: Yes. Your friend is a money mule. You don't want to be one! https://www.fbi.gov/news/stories/fbi-joins-international-campaign-to-stop-money-mules-121718

Comment: Technically, we haven't established that her friend is *receiving* money from these people, only that she is *sending* it to them.  Still 100% scam, however.  OP definitely should not join her friend in this endeavour (and should probably try harder to stop her.)

Answer (score 5):

Why does she need you to transfer money for her? Why can't she just do it herself?

You don't say much about who these guys are that she's sending money to and why. That statement brings up all sorts of red flags that she is the victim of some kind of scam. Or, as others indicate, that she is involved in some sort of money laundering -- knowingly or unknowingly. Either way, I'd want to learn a whole lot more before I would even think of becoming involved. If I thought a friend was a victim of a scam, I certainly would not want to help him be victimized, even if there was no risk to me. And if it's a scam, there likely is risk to you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Also you need to wonder why she wants you to be involved. The limits for sending money through western union are quite high. Also if everything's perfectly legit there would likely be other methods of transfer that are easier and cheaper.